# How long does a Rails ENV variable persist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, environment-variables

In config/boot.rb, if set some environment variable:

ENV['some'] = 1

Will that stay in memory across requests (for both development and production environments)?  The only time it is deleted is when the application shuts down, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will stay on memory for the lifetime of the process.

> Will that stay in memory across requests

It will, but beware of the following gotcha: If you are using a multi-process server (such as unicorn, rainbows, passenger, puma in cluster mode etc) AND you modify the environment variable after the application boot, the change *won't* be shared between the different application instances.

Run (and play with) this example to get a better idea: (`fork` is what multi-process servers do to spawn multiple instances).

```
ENV["some"] = "1"
puts "Value on master process: #{ENV['some']}"

fork do
  puts "Initial value on process 1: #{ENV['some']}"

  sleep 1
  ENV["some"] = "2"
  puts "Final value on process 1: #{ENV['some']}"
end

fork do
  puts "Initial value on process 2: #{ENV['some']}"

  # Wait for the process 1 to finish
  sleep 2
  puts "Final value on process 2: #{ENV['some']}"
end

Process.waitall
```

Output:

```
Value on master process: 1
Initial value on process 1: 1
Initial value on process 2: 1
Final   value on process 1: 2
Final   value on process 2: 1
```

The change of `ENV['some']` on "process 1" isn't seen from "process 2", even though they are initially the same (and both inherit it from the "master" process).

Comment: Thanks, so if a user is logged in on a particular application instance, if you modify the ENV variable on that instance, the user will see that until they log out?  In other words, a logged in user stays in one application instance/process until they log out.  Or is it because of the stateless connection, that they could be hitting a different process/instance that is different from the one they logged in on?

Comment: You have no guarantee that the user will hit the same instance of the application. As you said, HTTP is a stateless protocol. If the data is specific to that user, you can throw it into a cookie (Rails' `session`), or create a new column in the database. If however it is to be shared with everyone, I would look into using redis, or create a new `ActiveRecord` model.